Finding Absolute Coordinates in a PDF
I've been digging into this and I just really need some help. I feel like this should be possible but I've not been able to figure it out as of yet.
I have a unique string that exists in a PDF. I want to find the X/Y coordinates (from the top left corner) of that string relative to the current page.
I'm using PHP. Currently I'm using TCPDF and FPDI to load the PDF.
I'm not expecting any encrypted pdf's. In fact, the PDF's that I'll be handling are dynamically generated from another script.
I also don't care about the contents of the unique string. It can be replaced with whatever, if it means that I can get the position in the PDF.
There are some questions on SO about this, but I haven't found any that clearly and explicitly answer the question.
How to get the X,Y coordinates of a point in a PDF doesn't really provide an answer.
How to get text position in PDF using PHP, TCPDF & FPDI? This doesn't have an accepted answer.
PHP PDF template library with PDF output? This has some thoughts... but nothing that explicitly answers the question.
Thanks for any help!

Why do you need this?

"I want to find the X/Y coordinates (from the top left corner) of that string relative to the current page." - You should not also say where the origin of your custom coordinate system shall be. You should also mention the size of a unit in your coordinate system (commonly 1/72 inch) and in which direction you have rising coordinate values (commonly rightwards and upwards).

@Olivier - the reason I need to know the position is so that I can then position a button over it which will allow a user to fill in values at that position. These values might be a signature, a company name, a date, etc... I have the interface working and am able to display buttons and accept values. The one piece I'm missing is the coordinates of where to place the buttons.

@mkl The origin of the coordinate system would be the top-left corner of the current page. The origin point would be 0,0. The rising coordinate values would proceed down and to the right. i.e. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSSOM_View/Coordinate_systems#dimensions
I don't necessarily need exact 1/72 inch precision. I'm open to using a percentage as well (10% from the left, 30% from the top).

With that information added to your question, people knowledgeable of the PDF tools you're using should be able to help. (I'm actually at home with other tools, mostly from the Java and .NET world.)

You can try smalot/pdfparser.

@Olivier Thanks! That's exactly what I needed, in fact the library offers an example on how to get the X/Y positions of a bit of text.
When I have time I might update this question with a legit answer which shows how I used the parser.
